# SQL select statement with except

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to generate a SQL statement where I need to get rid of all 'users' that have a certain trait attributed to them. Here is the example here

```
+------+-------+
| User | Trait |
+------+-------+
| A    | Fire  |
| A    | Water |
| A    | Air   |
| B    | Water |
| B    | Air   |
| C    | Water |
| C    | Fire  |
+------+-------+
```

With SQL I'd like to remove all users who have the trait fire associated with them.

So basically, afterwards, we'd be left with

```
+------+-------+
| User | Trait |
+------+-------+
| B    | Water |
| B    | Air   |
+------+-------+
```

If I was able to use something in excel to filter it out instead of through SQL, this would work as well. I've been looking through various ways, but from what I've tried, most will only remove the single row with the trait, but not the user along with it.

I need sql to translate something in the lines of

```
For (i = table.length; i++)
    If Trait = Fire
        getVal(User(i))
    DeleteRows(User(i))
```

I'm looked into sql except, but the table I'm using is quite a bit more complex, so some help using a basic example would be nice to lead me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Delete rows from the table?  Or just not select them?

Comment: You had a choice between two answers, one using NOT IN and the other NOT EXISTS. They are equivalent if `user` (or is it `userid`?) is NOT NULL. If it may be null, then NOT IN will likely NOT produce the desired result. If you have a row with user=NULL and Trait='Fire', then NULL, 'Fire' will be in the result set of the subquery, and NOT IN will result in the rejection of ALL ROWS in the outer query. In most cases NOT EXISTS is safer.

Comment: Thanks for the info, luckily none of the information has any NULL values, so I was able to fix up a NOT IN and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-select and discard userids with `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM mytable WHERE Trait = 'Fire')
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I tested it out on my query and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is using `not exists`.

```
select * 
from tablename t
where not exists (select 1 from tablename where userid = t.userid and Trait = 'Fire')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select a.user, a.trait
  from the_table a
 where not exists
( select null
    from the_table b
   where b.user = a.user
     and b.trait = 'Fire'
);
```